# Adding more files to the ClientBin for Silverlight in an ASP.net MVC app

Tags: asp.net-mvc, silverlight, silverlight-3.0

I have an asp.net MVC app that also has a silverlight project for some sprinkled in effects and functionality... I just added a new file to my silverlight project and am at a loss in how to migrate it over to the clientbin in the MVC application

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess I wasn't very clear in my question but I figured it out... I'll set a variable in the page and redirect based on that to individual xaml pages within the silverlight application